# Google Cloud Storage Bucket From Unity IOS Project - Error deserializing JSON credential data

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to test out a new feature in my iOS Unity app and am looking to gather data on how quickly user's skip certain scenes.

As part of that, I want store that data so I can analyze it. It may not be the most practical method but since this is just for a limited beta release I am trying to use a Google Cloud storage bucket to send .txt files of that information so I can collate it.

The below script works just fine when I am running it on my Unity Editor, it sends the .txt file with the time at which the scene was ended. However, when I build and run the project on an iOS device I get the following error in Xcode's output...

**Error uploading file to Google Cloud Storage: Error deserializing JSON credential data.
d__18:MoveNext()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBuilder:Start(TStateMachine&)
ReturnHome:UploadLogFileToGCS(String)
ReturnHome:OnSkipButtonClicked()
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent:Invoke()
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchPress(PointerEventData, Boolean, Boolean)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchEvents()
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:Process()**

Is there any way to fix this issue or is there a fundamental incompatibility between iOS and what I am trying to do?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.Video;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO;
using System;
using Google.Cloud.Storage.V1;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;

public class ReturnHome : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Canvas canvas; // Assign this variable in the Inspector
    public GameObject uiButton; // Assign this variable in the Inspector
    public SpriteRenderer playButton; // Assign this variable in the Inspector
    public GameObject skipButtonPrefab; // Assign this variable in the Inspector
    public GameObject SkipButtonVerticalPrefab; // Assign this variable in the Inspector
    public VideoPlayer videoPlayer; // Assign this variable in the Inspector
    private bool videoStarted = false; // Flag for checking if Video Player started playing
    private float delay = 10f; // The delay in seconds
    private bool buttonPressed = false; // Flag for checking if UI button is pressed
    private float videoStartTime;
    private string serviceAccountKeyPath;

    private void Awake()
    {
        serviceAccountKeyPath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "configgoogle.json");
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        // Disable the UI button at the start of the scene
        Debug.Log("UI button disabled");

        // Find the playButton object if it is not assigned
        if (playButton == null)
        {
            playButton = GameObject.Find("PlayButton").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        }

        // Find the videoPlayer object if it is not assigned
        if (videoPlayer == null)
        {
            videoPlayer = GameObject.Find("VideoPlayer").GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
        }

        // Reset the flag when the scene is loaded
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
    }

    private void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
    {
        // Find the canvas object if it is not assigned
        if (canvas == null)
        {
            canvas = FindObjectOfType<Canvas>();
        }

        videoStarted = false;
    }

    private void LoadSceneDelayed()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("MainMenu");
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // Check if Video Player started playing and start the delay
        if (!videoStarted && videoPlayer != null && videoPlayer.isPlaying)
        {
            videoStarted = true;
            Debug.Log("Video Player started playing");
            videoStartTime = Time.time;
            Invoke("GenerateSkipButton", delay);
        }
    }

    private void GenerateSkipButton()
    {
        GameObject skipButtonPrefabToInstantiate = skipButtonPrefab;
        Vector3 skipButtonPosition = new Vector3(720, 320, 0);

        // Get the name of the scene
        string sceneName = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name;

        if (sceneName == "Scene Boxing")
        {
            skipButtonPrefabToInstantiate = SkipButtonVerticalPrefab;
            skipButtonPosition = new Vector3(-450, 0, 0);
        }

        GameObject skipButton = Instantiate(skipButtonPrefabToInstantiate, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
        skipButton.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);
        skipButton.transform.localPosition = skipButtonPosition;

        // Set the OnClick event handler of the skip button
        Button skipButtonComponent = skipButton.GetComponent<Button>();
        skipButtonComponent.onClick.AddListener(OnSkipButtonClicked);
    }

    private void OnSkipButtonClicked()
    {
        // Define filePath variable
        string sceneName = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name;
        string dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss");
        string filePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/log_" + sceneName + "_" + dateTime + ".txt";

        // Log the skip button press event to the file
        File.AppendAllText(filePath, "Skip button pressed at: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "\n");

        // Upload the log file to Google Cloud Storage
        UploadLogFileToGCS(filePath);

        // Load the main menu scene
        SceneManager.LoadScene("MainMenu");
    }

    private async void UploadLogFileToGCS(string filePath)
    {
        try
        {
            // Load the Google Cloud service account key file
            GoogleCredential credential;
            using (var stream = new FileStream(serviceAccountKeyPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream);
            }

            // Create an instance of the storage client
            var storageClient = StorageClient.Create(credential);

            // Read the file data
            byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            string bucketName = "hapbetastorage"; // Replace with your Google Cloud Storage bucket name

            // Upload the file to Google Cloud Storage
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(fileData))
            {
                await storageClient.UploadObjectAsync(bucketName, fileName, null, stream);
            }

            Debug.Log("Uploaded file to Google Cloud Storage: " + filePath);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Error uploading file to Google Cloud Storage: " + e.Message);
        }
    }


    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        // Define filePath variable
        string sceneName = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name;
        string dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss");
        string filePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/log_" + sceneName + "_" + dateTime + ".txt";

        // Log the application quit event to the file
        File.AppendAllText(filePath, "Application quit at: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "\n");

        // Upload the log file to Google Cloud Storage
        UploadLogFileToGCS(filePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the credentials file actually JSON? Also, this approach isn't super safe since someone could reuse your credentials to access your bucket (or worse, depending on how fine-grained the service account's permissions are).

Comment: You have a major security design problem. Do not use credentials from a service account on user devices. Google will block those credentials. You must use Google OAuth from user credentials.